# Creating a Java increasing alphabet grid with a 5x5 array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The grid I need to recreate looks like this

```
 ABCDE
T.....F
S.....G
R.....H
Q.....I
P.....J
 ONMLK
```

The grid I have now looks like this

```
 ABCDE
0.....0
1.....1
2.....2
3.....3
4.....4
 ONMLK
```

My code for creating the grid

```
// * Method * Creating the maze grid
public static void createMazeGrid(){
    // First section of Maze Grid
    System.out.print("  ");
    for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet < 'F'; alphabet++)
        System.out.print(alphabet);
    System.out.println();

    // Middle section of Maze Grid
    // *TRY TO FIGURE OUT ALPHABET GRID*
    for(int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++) {
            maze[i][j] = ".";
            if (j == 0)
                System.out.print(i + maze[i][j]);
            else if (j == maze[i].length - 1)
                System.out.print(maze[i][j] + i);
            else
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Last section of Maze Grid
    System.out.print("  ");
    for(char alphabet = 'O'; alphabet > 'J'; alphabet--)
        System.out.print(alphabet);
    System.out.println();
}
```

I have already declared these variables in the public class, not my main method. How would I achieve this? I tried changing the int's in the middle section of my map to char like my top and bottom section but it just cuts the middle portion of the map out.

---

public static int numRows = 5;

---

public static int numCols = 5;

---

public static String[][] maze = new String[numRows][numCols];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to complete your code is the use of chars where you already have your output.

```
public class Maze {
    public static int numRows = 5;
    public static int numCols = 5;
    public static String[][] maze = new String[numRows][numCols];
// * Method * Creating the maze grid
public static void createMazeGrid(){
    // First section of Maze Grid
    System.out.print("  ");
    for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet < 'F'; alphabet++)
        System.out.print(alphabet);
    System.out.println();

    // Middle section of Maze Grid
    // *TRY TO FIGURE OUT ALPHABET GRID*
    for(int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < maze[i].length; j++) {
            maze[i][j] = ".";
            if (j == 0)
                System.out.print((char)('T' - i) + maze[i][j]); // left side
            else if (j == maze[i].length - 1)
                System.out.print(maze[i][j] + (char)('F' + i)); // right side
            else
                System.out.print(maze[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Last section of Maze Grid
    System.out.print("  ");
    for(char alphabet = 'O'; alphabet > 'J'; alphabet--)
        System.out.print(alphabet);
    System.out.println();
}
public static void main(String[] args) { createMazeGrid(); }
}
```

Now let's test it:

```
$ java Maze.java
  ABCDE
 T.....F
 S.....G
 R.....H
 Q.....I
 P.....J
  ONMLK
```

Looks good. :-)